# WatchOS debug crashlog

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, symbolicate

We have got the dsyms file and the crashlog from the archive file which is used to generate the IPA in xcode.
I have used the following command in terminal to fetch the filename and crash location in the project.

```
atos -arch armv7k -o  dSymfilelocation -l LoadAddress AddressToSymbolicate
```

Using the above command the most of the results are shown without the lineNumber.

1->The result i have got is pointing to the stringConstants file and the line number is pointing to serviceName constant.

```
struct Keys {
     static let serviceName = "serviceName"
     // More constants....
}
```

2-> The other result is pointing to the locationmanager delegate in WKInterfaceController.However location manager is already assigned in the class.

```
private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.

        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
```

What would be the reason for above crashes?

For most of the crashlogs I got file name,function name and line number as 0 as results. And for some of the crashlogs the SymbolicatedAddress is shown as result.

Even I tried the command `SymbolicateCrash`.However it returns the same file as the crashlog, there were no difference between the crash log and symbolicated file.

```
symbolicatecrash CrashLog.crash dsymFileLocation > Symbolicated.crash
```

Crashlog file:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: CAROUSEL, Snapshot watchdog transgression. Exhausted CPU time allowance of 2.00 seconds. Elapsed total CPU time (seconds) 7.69 (user 7.69, system 0.00), 99% CPU. Elapsed application CPU time (seconds) 2.79, 35% CPU.
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, CSLSceneSnapshotAction watchdog transgression: com.usa.com.usa.watchkitapp.watchkitextension exhausted CPU time allowance of 2.00 seconds | <FBExtensionProcess: 0xb060d20; NissanLeaf Watc (com.usa.com.usa.watchkitapp.watchkitextension); pid: 669; typeID: com.apple.watchkit; host: Carousel:30> Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 7.690 (user 7.690, system 0.000), 96% CPU | Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 2.794, 35% CPU, lastUpdate 2019-01-20 14:51:53 +0000
Triggered by Thread:  0
```